# How can I root my 4.4.2 Razr Maxx HD Verizon

Tags: rooting, motorola-droid-razr

I've tried everything that I can think of to try and root my Razr Droid Maxx HD Verizon phone, running 4.4.2.
Towel root, sunshine and I can't even remember all of the others I tried. Nothing works!

Comment: I changed your tag from root to rooting. while waiting for answers you might wish to follow up to our [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) – and from there to the "[rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)", which also includes some generic methods. Note, I added this question specifically for the Razr Maxx HD in the rooting index, so there is not a specific solution there, this will be it or "generic" methods.

Comment: Verizon bootloaders are all locked. So there is no way to root Verizon-custom phones. Consider buying an international version next time. :)

Comment: How in the hell would somebody know that...damnit

Answer (score 0):

Successfully used the Hydrogen Peroxide method as outlined at this link.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/droid-razr-hd/general/root-droid-razr-hd-xt926-183-46-15-t3062040

Had to reflash stock firmware a priori though. Others had success without flashing, only factory reset prior to attempt.

Newest Kingroot or KingoRoot would be worth trying 1st.

Comment: Hi! Can you list the instructions needed to use Hydrogen Peroxide? I know I can read them in the link but we've a policy of removing answers which are not self-sufficient but heavily relies on a link.