# How to Root a Droid RAZR HD running Android 4.4.2?

Tags: rooting, motorola-droid-razr

I'm trying to root my Motorola Droid RAZR HD running Android 4.4.2, and I can't find any working instructions anywhere for how to root it. I've looked over the XDA Developer forums, but many results assume that the phone is already rooted.

I've made sure that all Motorola drivers are updated on my computer, as well as having developer mode unlocked on the phone.

I've tried following the XDA thread here: <s>http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1943851</s>, and when I run the run.bat file, the console either gets stuck on "Waiting for device" or "daemon started successfully", after which nothing happens. I've left both results running for >30min, with no results.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here with this guide, or is there a better/simpler way to root the phone? Also, do I need to factory reset my phone prior to rooting for best results, or can rooting be performed on a used phone?

I have checked the rooting index, and the Droid RAZR HD isn't indexed.

EDIT: I have been informed by Tamoghna Chowdhury that the above link is for Android 4.0 ICS, not 4.4.2 KitKat.

Comment: Is the phone showing `USB Debugging Connected` in the notifications area when you plug it into your computer?

Comment: Also, the thread you linked is for Android 4.0 ICS. I suspect it won't work for KitKat

Comment: Probably the drivers also won't work.

Comment: Confirmed. This won't work. It uses a root exploit limited to ICS only.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/droid-razr-hd/general/root-droid-razr-hd-xt926-183-46-15-t3062040) out?

Comment: @Tamoghna Chowdhury USB Debugging is connected.

Comment: The link you posted has a download for Hydrogen Peroxide, but my antivirus blocked it because it was an Android Rooter. Can you confirm if this is a problem?

Comment: Of course it is an Android rooter.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, but it's at your own risk (Note: People won't get away with posting malware on XDA, so you needn't worry)

Comment: Also, if you don't want that, use TowelRoot or KingoRoot.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93449/how-can-i-root-my-4-4-2-razr-maxx-hd-verizon?rq=1

Comment: As documented in the linked question, TowelRoot may not work.

Comment: My kernel is recent enough to fall into the Hydrogen Peroxide category according to your XDA link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36203/discussion-between-tamoghna-chowdhury-and-unixcurious).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tamoghna Chowdhury for the links to the XDA Developers thread. Apparently, my kernel date is too new and I can't unlock the bootloader on my phone. In order to root it, I would need to flash XT926 firmware on it as well. Closing question.